# Grouping regular expressions in a class library?

Tags: c#, regex

I know this is probably personal preference, but what is your preferred method of grouping regular expressions.  Do you just have one class with all regular expressions or do you separate them out by type (strings, numbers, etc) or something like by usage (emails, phone, ssn)

Comment: `static readonly` fields where needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep them close to where they are used, as private static members of the using class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to update them a lot such as for a parser where you don't control the input data then maybe you group them so that it is easy to do updates, otherwise as was said I just keep them in the classes I use them in.